# Am I missing something within the change method?

Tags: java, object, methods

The change method of the PlaneTester class is not working properly. The only line of the method that works as intended is the `v.setX(8.4);` line.  `u = new PlanePoint(3.2, 74);` and `w = u;` are having zero effect on the output.

```
public class PlanePoint
{
     private double x;
     private double y;

    public PlanePoint(double first, double second)
   {
        x = first;
        y = second;
    }

    public void setX(double n)
   {
        x = n;
    }

    public void setY(double n)
    {
         y = n;
     }

     public double getX( )
    {
         return x;
    }

    public double getY( )
    {
         return y;
     }

     public String toString( )
    {
         return "(" + x + "," + y + ")"; 
     }
}
```

```
public class PlaneTester
{
     public static void main(String[ ] args)
    {
         PlanePoint a = new PlanePoint(6.2, 1.9);
         PlanePoint b = new PlanePoint(2.8, 5.6);
         PlanePoint c = new PlanePoint(4.9, 6.4);
         System.out.println(a+" "+b+" "+c);
         change(a, b, c);
         System.out.println(a+" "+b+" "+c);
         change(b, c, a);
         System.out.println(a+" "+b+" "+c);
     }

     public static void change(PlanePoint  u, PlanePoint  v, PlanePoint  w)
    {
           u = new PlanePoint(3.2, 74);
           v.setX(8.4);
           w = u;
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:
(6.2,1.9) (2.8,5.6) (4.9,6.4)
(6.2,1.9) (8.4,5.6) (4.9,6.4)
(6.2,1.9) (8.4,5.6) (8.4,6.4)

EXPECTED OUTPUT:
(6.2,1.9) (2.8,5.6) (4.9,6.4)
(3.2,74) (8.4,5.6) (3.2,74)
(3.2,74) (3.2,74) (8.4,6.4)

Comment: `u = new PlanePoint(3.2, 74);` and `w = u;` only change `u` and `w` inside the method, not the objects passed to the method. See the linked duplicate for an explanation.